# How to know if a site is Multilingual programmatically?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

In Drupal 7 I used drupal_multilingual() to know if a site is multilingual, but [this function was renamed in Drupal 8 to language_multilingual()](https://www.drupal.org/node/1392312), the problem is that it seems that [language_multilingual() is not longer available](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8.0.x/search/language_multilingual).

I found that [LanguageManager::isMultilingual](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Language!LanguageManager.php/function/LanguageManager%3A%3AisMultilingual/8.2.x) should return:

> bool TRUE if more than one language is added, FALSE otherwise.

But when you go to see the code always FALSE is returned.

```
public function isMultilingual() {
  return FALSE;
}
```

This is an error or I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `LanguageManager` always returns false when you check for multilingual, because you need to install the Language module to configure a multilingual site. This module provides a proper check for multilingual by replacing the class `LanguageManager` with `ConfigurableLanguageManager`:

*Drupal\language\LanguageServiceProvider::alter*

```
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('language_manager');
    $definition->setClass('Drupal\language\ConfigurableLanguageManager')
    ...
```

*Drupal\language\ConfigurableLanguageManager::isMultilingual()*

```
public function isMultilingual() {
    return count($this->getLanguages(LanguageInterface::STATE_CONFIGURABLE)) > 1;
  }
```

So you can use the service `language_manager`, injected in a class or from the static service container wrapper `Drupal`:

*Drupal::languageManager()*

```
  /**
   * Returns the language manager service.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface
   *   The language manager.
   */
  public static function languageManager() {
    return static::getContainer()->get('language_manager');
  }
```

to use in all cases the correct class:

`\Drupal::languageManager()->isMultilingual()`

Answer (score 2):

Searching I found in [drupalcontrib a reference to the language_multilingual()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/language_multilingual/8) function that show the following code:

```
function language_multilingual() {
  return Drupal::languageManager()->isMultilingual();
}
```

So I used `Drupal::languageManager()->isMultilingual();` and it seems that returns the good value.

I'll do tomorrow a test in a not multilingual site to confirm.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The [`LanguageManager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Language%21LanguageManager.php/class/LanguageManager/8.2.x) class is the wrong class to use, since it is defined as follows.

> Class responsible for providing language support on language-unaware sites.

Given that description, and the fact there is a service using that class, the correct code should instantiate a service, which is what the code in install.core.inc does. (See [`install_tasks()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21install.core.inc/function/install_tasks/8.2.x).)

```
  // Determine whether a translation file must be imported during the
  // 'install_import_translations' task. Import when a non-English language is
  // available and selected. Also we will need translations even if the
  // installer language is English but there are other languages on the system.
  $needs_translations = (count($install_state['translations']) > 1 && !empty($install_state['parameters']['langcode']) && $install_state['parameters']['langcode'] != 'en') || \Drupal::languageManager()->isMultilingual();
```

So, the correct code to use in procedural code is the following.

```
$is_multi_lingual = \Drupal::languageManager()->isMultilingual();
```

When using a class, and when it is possible, the service should be injected, and it instance saved in a object property (e.g. `$this->languageManager`). In that case, the code is the following.

```
$is_multi_lingual = $this->languageManager->isMultilingual();
```

The service ID for the language manager is [language_manager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/language_manager/8.2.x).

Comment: Both answers are correct. When installing the module Language the class is switched to `ConfigurableLanguageManager` in the service container. So the code from both answers always uses the correct class.